How can you portably echo a shell string without using printf?
I want to write the contents of a shell variable into a pipe, as it is, without modification. "echo -n" would be nice too.
Everyone says "use printf", something like
echo() {
    case "$1" in
    -n) shift; printf '%s' "$*" ;;
    *) printf '%s\n' "$*" ;;
    esac
}

but as printf is an external command, the number of characters it can take as an argument is limited, typically to 131072 or 65536, maybe less, depending on the OS. I'm processing json lists of issues, which can be hundreds of K long, and it has to work everywhere.
You can't use "echo -e" because dash's built-in echo always maps backslash sequences.
There has to be a way in basic shell, without using an external program, to write the contents of a variable into a pipe or into a file.
Doesn't there?

but as printf is an external command, is it? type -a printf printf is a shell builtin. What shell are you using?

ok, I see, dash. In my version printf is also a builtin.

FWIW posh also seems to have echo -e enabled by default.

I'm processing json lists of issues, which can be hundreds of K long are you asking XY question? If you are processing such jsons, use jq or perl or python. Use files, use cat to print such json and redirections. Shell has no support for json. There has to be a way in basic shell you are processing json and are concerned about one external program? Is your issue speed or portability? Shell is full of external programs, shell is a thing that exists to run external programs. How do you intent to do anythin with that json without external programs?

@KamilCuk I think OP's concerned about getting outsized shell variables to an external program. Bludgeoning tools into service they were never meant for is an ancient and honorable pastime, I'm not going to fault anyone for that :-)

If your problem is argument limits, then don't try to pass every argument at once. Just because you want to do something does not mean you can do it trivially.

@arkadiusz-drabczyk AIX and Solaris' /bin/sh and OpenBSD's ksh don't have it built in, maybe others

yourprogram <<EOD
$longlongstring
EOD

This will add a newline on the end, which is fine for json data, and anything that was loaded from command substitution will have had a trailing newline stripped anyway; to avoid adding it (back) you can
lf=`printf '\n.'`; lf=${lf%.}
yourprogram <<EOD
${longlongstring%$lf}
EOD

to strip any trailing newline off the end before ensuring it has one. The shell itself works exclusively with text; in portable text files, lines end in a newline.
btw, in what shell is printf not a builtin? I tried read -d '' </usr/include/vulkan/vulkan_structs.hpp; printf %s "$REPLY" | wc -c; echo ${#REPLY} and got 5539603 5539603, builtins don't have an arguments-length limit.

This doesn't provide a way to omit the final newline, though.

The whole "which shell" line of inquiry is beside the point. For a portable script you follow POSIX, period. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/printf.html

proper text always has a final newline (and if we're following POSIX that's a hard requirement), and OP's processing json.

Uh, but then why else would they care about implementing echo -n? That's the entire point of their function. I guess if you are piecing together JSON from substrings you'd want to be able to print [ without a final newline, for example.

I was going off "I'm processing json lists of issues". The shell is for text.

Though awk 'NR > 1 { printf "\n" } { printf "%s", $0 }' would work in place of cat if you needed to trim the final newline from a potentially multi-line string.

I think you lost track of "without an external program". cat was a stand-in for whatever OP wants to pipe to, i'll fix it to make that more apparent.

"in what shell is printf an external" doesn't really make sense. Any platform can provide an external printf command (a POSIX-compliant operating system must have printf available, regardless of which shell is being used), but any shell may also provide a printf built-in to shadow the external command for efficiency.

@chepner okay, but the question was about piping shell variables from a shell. Without using external commands. So an external printf existing wasn't my side queestion, it was a builtin printf not existing.

@jthrill: json is text, fab answer; solved specific problem by dumping it in a file not a variable and using "jq 'command' file" but the niggle remained.

@tripleee: Because the issue title musn't have a final newline but the issue body yes. Not that titles can be 168k but

There should be, but I think you have simply identified a problem in POSIX.
The simple fix would be to make printf a shell builtin.
In the meantime, xargs to the rescue.
echo () {
   local newline_maybe='\n'
   case $1 in
    -n) shift; newline_maybe='';;
   esac
   command echo "$*" | xargs printf '%s'
   printf "$newline_maybe"
}

local is in POSIX since a couple versions back, though IIRC there are still shells which don't support it.
echo () {
   case $1 in
    -n) shift; command echo "$*" | xargs printf '%s';;
     *) command echo "$*" | xargs printf '%s'; printf '\n';;
    esac
}

Though if your echo processes backslash sequences, it's turtles all the way down.

Yes, ksh calls it "typeset" so you have to "test -n "$KSH_VERSION" && alias local=typeset" Gak!
